# Problem in UTF Encoding in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

I use the following lines of code:

```
$revTerm =  "". strrev($limitAry["term"]);
$revTerm = utf8_encode($revTerm);
```

The $revTerm contains Norwegian characters as ø æ å. However, it is shown correctly. I need to reverse them before displaying, so I use the first line. 
When I display them this way, I get an error of bad xml format - used to fill a grid. 
When I try to use the second line, I don't get an error but the characters are not shown correctly. Could there be any other way to solve that?
If it may help, I use jqGrid to fill those data in.

Comment: As you use `utf8_encode`, the string in `$limitAry["term"]` is encoded with ISO 8859-1, right?

Comment: The string is already destroyed before he calls `utf8_encode`. Since `strrev` is written for single-byte encodings, it swaps the order of bytes that were part of single multi-byte characters, effectively turning them into different characters or nonsensical byte sequences.

Comment: @Dan Grossman: I just don’t see the point for `utf8_encode`. If `$limitAry["term"]` were ISO 8859-1 (or any other single-byte character encoding), `strrev` would work and `utf8_encode` would convert that reversed string to UTF-8 (including incorrect mapping if `$limitAry["term"]` is not ISO 8859-1). But if `$limitAry["term"]` already were UTF-8, `strrev` would not work properly and using `utf8_encode` wouldn’t make any sense as it’s already UTF-8. But none of these scenarios explain the XML error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strrev`, like most PHP string functions, is not safe for multi-byte encodings.

Comment: To be fair, it can be used for UCS-2 and UCS-4, however it changes the endianness of the string.

Comment: You'll have to write it yourself, right, and only make use of the functions in PHP's multibyte library (which doesn't include a built-in string reversing function): http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

Answer (score 3):

try this example

```
$test = 'А роза упала на лапу Азора ウィキ';
$test = iconv('utf-8', 'utf-16le', $test);
$test = strrev($test);
// キィウ арозА упал ан алапу азор А
echo iconv('utf-16be', 'utf-8', $test);
```

(russian)
http://bolknote.ru/2012/04/02/~3625#56

Comment: Short explanation for people, who don't understand Russian: this will correctly reverse order of most multibyte string as long as they consist from single-codepoint symbols. It abuses the fact, that byte-by-byte reversion of UTF-16 produces correctly reversed UTF-16 string, but in different endianess. It won't work for complex graphemes (such as most emojis, certain forms of characters with accents etc). A handy article about the multi-codepoint symbols: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsClusters.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$revTerm = utf8_decode($limitAry["term"]);
$revTerm = strrev($revTerm);
$revTerm = utf8_encode($revTerm);
```

For using `strrev` you have to decode your string to a non-multibyte string.

Comment: That only works if all the characters in the string exist in the ISO-8859-1 character set